# Замена при помощи preg_replace

Tags: регулярные-выражения, php

Помогите сделать замену с `[url=https://siter.com]Таракан[/url]`
На `<a href="https://site.com">Таракан</a>` При помощи `preg_replac`e

P.S. Просто не знаю, как составить регулярку

Comment: markdown сразу ставьте и приближайте всеобщее счастье с еще одним сервисом, поддерживающим этот язык разметки.

Comment: Не хочу =(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как-то так,

```
preg_replace('/\[url=(.+?)\](.+?)\[\/url\]/', '<a href="\1">\2</a>', $MY_TEXT);
```